# Unable to boot USB drive Fujitsu AH531; windows always boots instead

Tags: bios, accessibility

I wish to blow away Windows from this laptop and install Linux.  However, the usual methods of gaining access to the BIOS (with a goal of booting a LiveImage Linux) have not succeeded so far.

According to the [instruction manual](http://www.fujitsupc.com/www/content/pdf/SupportGuides/AH531_BIOS_Guide_FPC58-2843-01_rA.pdf) (page 2), pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, or <kbd>F12</kbd> should work.  The *Fujitsu* logo does appear and displays those keys in the legend at the bottom of screen.  But no matter what I do, it always boots Windows.

Looking for similar answers, it doesn't seem as though anyone else has the problem of not being able to access the BIOS, either UEFI or "legacy mode".

Any ideas?

Comment: We have, @wallyk, Fortunately or UnFortunately. We have recently reinstalled a _MicroSoft_ _Windows_ **10** _Home_ Non-_N_ 64-Bit Operating System Software Installation due to a Failed System Restore Point Restoration Procedure that has been documented on one of the Web-Pages of this Web-Site. To our utter amazement, it has been incredibly difficult to use the Basic Input-Output System. We would not blame the Hardware Equipment for this weird behavior. Eventually, it has worked out, but after a number of Irrational Insistent Attempts. Just keep trying.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai:  How did you do it?  I am unclear what I should keep trying.

Comment: We completely understand your desire to blow away the _MicroSoft_ _Windows_ **10** Operating System Software Installation from your side, @wallyk. During the recent Failure that we have endured, even the Operating System Image Restoration Procedure has failed with an uncanny Error Message that was complaining that the specified Operating System Image had been performed on a different Machine, while it was quite recent and it had definitely been performed on the _same_ Machine.

Comment: The Error Message was also specifying that the _different_ Machine had _B.I.O.S._ while this _other_ Machine has _U.E.F.I._ We can imagine that some Software Fault has been introduced somewhere related to the _B.I.O.S._-_U.E.F.I._ Competition. We have basically done nothing special. After a number of attempts, we have simply been able to enter the _B.I.O.S._

Comment: How was the usb drive prepared? it should be prepared for uefi boot using Rufus

Comment: What brand of computer are you trying to get into the bios on?

Comment: @Moab:  It is a Fujitsu laptop, a Lifebook A Series, Model AH531, Product number FPC03448AP.  Production date may be September 2011.

Comment: Ok, F2 is bios key and F12 is a boot menu, F12 is what you should use to select the usb drive to boot, start tapping F12 when you see the splash screen. If it is W10 it may be in hibernate mode, if you can boot into windows hold the Shift key down when you select Restart, this should allow bios access.

Comment: @Moab:  The first USB I tried was prepared by someone else.  I examined it with Fedora 27 and it showed no valid partitions.  Then I tried booting a Fedora 27 LiveUSB created with Fedora 27 which works correctly on several other systems.  Wikipedia does not mention [Rufus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rufus) as anything related to computers, so what is it and why do I need it?  AFAIK, there is nothing special about a USB volume prepared for UEFI vs. legacy.

Comment: @Moab:  I have tried F2, F12, and <kbd>Esc</kbd> multiple times always starting the computer via a cold boot.  I accomplish that by disconnecting power and pulling the battery pack out for 10+ seconds.  I'll try Shift-restart to see if there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that some keys on the keyboard don't work very well.  In particular, <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> have to be pressed *very* vigorously for them to work reliably.

I got the first clue to this when @Moab asked the make of the computer—that got me to look at the labels glued onto the bottom.  When I saw that it is (probably) of 2011 vintage, I began to notice that some keys and buttons don't work so well.

Why didn't I notice that before?  Well, it was Windows running and I don't have much respect for Windows reliability.  Mouse clicking has all kinds of unresponsiveness issues similar to issues with MSDOS 3.0.  (Does anyone else remember how frequently Microsoft released mouse driver updates around 1985?)